# Conditional Ajax inclusion

Tags: ajax, conditional-content, include

I have a custom interface that uses 30+ ajax files while running...
some files are only used in category.php while othere's are only
used in page.php...

i include the ajax loader php files in my functions.php file

**example:**

```
include TEMPLATEPATH . '/ajaxLoops/ajax-open_client_editform.php';
include TEMPLATEPATH . '/ajaxLoops/ajax-submit_client_editform.php';
```

It all works great but when i tried to conditionally load them
using is_page or is_category directly in my functions.php the ajax
functions stop working.

example:

```
if(is_page()) {
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/ajaxLoops/ajax-open_client_editform.php';
}
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/ajaxLoops/ajax-submit_client_editform.php';
```

i guess this is a matter of loading order or some other issues i am
unaware of.... Could you help me understand the problem with my approach
or an alternative way of conditionally loading this files?...

Cheers,
Sagive.

**EDIT 1 (.PHP AJAX LOADER FILE):**

```
<?php
wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-simple-example', get_stylesheet_directory_uri().'/ajaxLoops/ajax-simple_example.js', array('jquery'), 1.0 ); // jQuery will be included automatically
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-simple-example', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) ); // setting ajaxurl

add_action( 'wp_ajax_action_simple_example', 'ajax_simple_example' ); // ajax for logged in users
function ajax_simple_example() {

    // just an empty example for my question
    // in stackexchange

    echo '<div id="success">'.$successMsg.'</div>';

    die(); // stop executing script
}
?>
```

Comment: Are you using wp_enqueue_scripts to load your .js files?

Comment: Yes... i have pasted and example in my question

Comment: Try putting a die() inside of the condition. That will show you whether the if condition is being met.

Comment: oh.. the condition is met... i echoed inside the condition to check that it working... the condition is being checked inside functions.php and not in my ajax loader file - the condition works but the ajax file doesent work. i guess its due to the load order meaning whne script are enqued and when wordpress can check if(is_page)

Comment: i also tried to hook the if(is_page()) to init, wp_head and a few more which made no difference..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call admin-ajax.php no query is being produced so `is_page()` or `is_category()` or any query based conditional tag will never return true.
A better way would be to include your files inside the ajax callback, meaning something like this:

```
add_action('wp_ajax_PAGE_ONLY_ACTION','PAGE_ONLY_Function');

function PAGE_ONLY_Function(){
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/ajaxLoops/ajax-open_client_editform.php';
    /**
     * do your page only ajax 
     */
    die();
}


add_action('wp_ajax_CATEGORY_ONLY_ACTION','CATEGORY_ONLY_Function');

function CATEGORY_ONLY_Function(){
    include TEMPLATEPATH . '/ajaxLoops/ajax-submit_client_editform.php';
    /**
     * do your Category only ajax 
     */
    die();
}
```

So this way you add your action hook all the time but include your files only when needed.

Comment: should the localize & enqueue commands stay in those ajax file? ... well, going to try it - thanks for the quick response

Comment: The localize & enqueue should and can be done inside the conditional tags and that way they are only enqueued when needed.

Comment: thanks a lot mate - sorry for the delay in my response - was called by the army to the Reserve :( ... works like a charm - thanks again

Comment: Hard times, I am on my way there myself :)

Comment: take your own coffe - new age coffee sux ;)

Comment: ok mate... apologies - i guess i still dont understand it  - Please check this - (inside functions.php) what am i doing wrong? http://pastebin.com/kjjujZka

Comment: Can you give a more "if page" / is_category etc" example? man? i am a bit stuck with multiple AJAX files loading each each time the functions.php is loaded..

Comment: @SagiveSEO contact me I'll try to help as much as i can :)